# Apache Camel, Problem merging XML documents via xslt-saxon

Tags: java, xslt, apache-camel, saxon

My camel route (spring boot application) receives a list of xml files, I would like to merge to one combined xml file via xslt transformation.

I am having trouble to perform the transformation in this route. I do not get any error message, the console log just gets blanked and nothing happens.

It has to do with the `document(concat('file:/',path))` statement.
When I remove this line, the transformation gets executed fine.
However if I perform this transformation via another processor, e.g. via Oxygen, everything works as expected (merging the files).

Have I missed something obviously here?

```
Spring boot: 2.5.4
Camel: 3.11.1

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-xslt-saxon</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.1</version>
</dependency>
```

This is the payload which is the input for the transformation.

```
<Modules>
    <module>
        <moduleId>000001</moduleId>
        <moduleType>L</moduleType>
        <fileName>abc1.xml</fileName>
        <path>S:\abc\files\abc.xml</path>
        <dueDate>2021-10-01</dueDate>
    </module>
    <module>
        <moduleId>000002</moduleId>
        <moduleType>L</moduleType>
        <fileName>abc2.xml</fileName>
        <path>S:\abc\files\abc2.xml</path>
        <dueDate>2021-10-01</dueDate>
    </module>
</Modules>
```

The camel route....

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
                              
    from("direct:deduplicateRoute")
        .routeId(IConstants.DEDUP_ROUTE)
        .to("xslt-saxon:file://C:/\Users/\abc/\development/\merge.xsl")
        .log("${body}");                  
}
```

and the xslt transformation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl=http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform
    xmlns:xs=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">      
        <Modules>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/Modules/module"/>
        </Modules>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/Modules/module">      
        <Module>
            <xsl:copy-of select="document(concat('file:/',path))"/>
        </Module>
    </xsl:template>     
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: In XSLT, the `document` function tends to work fine with a URL, in the case of a `file:` protocol URL that would be e.g. `file:///S:/abc/files/abc.xml`, you seem to want to construct something like `file:/S:\abc\files\abc.xml`

Comment: So perhaps, if you can, make sure the XML has URLs and not local file paths, or try to convert them using `replace(., '\\', '/')` to URLs.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but that did not seem to be the reason. I directly changed the path in the xml to the format you suggested. Again, perfect translation in IDE (Oxygen), when running via camel, the console blanks, the app stays active and nothing happens. Weird!

Comment: I double checked with `doc-available(path)` which returns to true. URL seems to be ok.

Comment: If `doc-available($path)` returns true then `doc($path)` should definitely return a result. `document($path)` could be different because they handle relative URIs differently in some cases. But in both cases, $path should be a URI, not a filename.